# Soil testing for new gardener

Tags: vegetables, soil, soil-amendment, soil-test

I'm a new gardener interested in getting my soil tested. Does anyone have a recommendation for a lab?

Comment: Worth noting, while you find the testing, what your neighbors grow. Roses, blueberries, and blue hydrangeas reveal acid soil. Cactus and perennial tulips reveal quick-draining soil. (Tuips, lily, lettuce, and hosta - no deer or rabbits.)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, kudos for testing your soil!

In the US, all (most?) states have an Extension service, usually connected to a major state university. Many or most of these extensions offer soil testing services. In Wisconsin, we have to pay a small fee for each test. I recommend seeing if your state's Extension offers this service before trying to use an independent lab - the Extension will probably be less expensive and may provide results quicker.

If you'd like further reading on soil additives, I recommend that you visit [this science-based site](https://puyallup.wsu.edu/lcs/). Scroll down until you get to the soil amendments section for a number of short white-papers that discuss various soil additives. There a lots of other papers there that contain great info, especially for new gardeners. There is also a link to The Garden Professors' Blog, which has searchable content that you may find useful.